# What kind of cabbage is this?

Tags: identification, brassicas, cabbage

This sprouted without us planting it. What is it? Leaves do not taste very much. [image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Looks like some other cole ,like kohlrabi ;it is difficult to identify from photo.

Comment: Yeah, the stems look like kohlrabi stems (without the bulbs, yet). The leaves look like collards (I'm not sure what kind of stems collards have).